# JPA query receive column name not valid

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I need to execute a very simply JPA Query
but I receive the error message "column name not valid". 
Obviously, if I execute manually the query it works fine, but not if I use JPA.

This is my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface OrdersRepositoryPayId extends JpaRepository<OrdersEntityPayId, Long> {
    
    @Query(value="select trackid from orders where payid=:payid" , nativeQuery=true)
    OrdersEntityPayId getOrdersByPaymentId(@Param("payid") String payid);
}
```

And this is the Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class OrdersEntityPayId {
    
    @Id
    private Long orderid;  // These are the table fields name
    private String payid;
    private String trackid; 
        // Getter and setter ....
}
```

And this is the oracle tabel primaryKey:

```
Database is Oracle.  Table name is ORDERS.  PrimaryKey is ORDERS.ORDERID NUMBER(16,0)
```

Could you pls indicate what I'm wrong?
Below the error I received:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: **could not execute
> query**; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> [..] [..] Caused by: **java.sql.SQLException: Nome colonna non valido**
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndexPrimitive(OracleStatement.java:4257)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:4215)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:299)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:626) 
> [...]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tried, but I receive the same error.

Comment: I found the reason.   We should have all the table columns in the Select list, otherwise the select fails.   e.g select o.orderid,o.payid,o.trackid from ORDERS o where o.payid=:payid